# Elegant way to transform formula with sum into code

Tags: function-construction

I have this formula, and many other which contains sum, I am perfectly able to do the computation over a list, however to do this I need to do it in several *manual* steps. Therefore, I wonder if there would be any elegant way of adding sequence to it or hold the expression or something similar making it run without needing to do step wise computation *manually*.

$$\frac{(x-\bar{x})}{\sum (x-\bar{x})^2}$$

Please note by manually I mean example calculating the mean first and then subtract it from the list and then sum it and so on.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this what you're trying to simplify? `x = Range[10]; y = Mean[x]; (x - y)/Sum[(i - y)^2, {i, x}]`

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Are you sure you want to divide by the sum? Usually in real applications the mean is divided by the square root of the sum. I know a nice way to do it.

Comment: Is the object to define such a quantity *without* using even the built-in `Mean`. (That's a reasonable thing to do -- "teaching the computer to do the calculation" -- in order to learn or reinforce learning how such mathematical/statistical things are defined.)

Comment: Or is the object simply to avoid any explicit use of expressions like `Sum[x[[1]], {i,1, n}]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are number of approaches including:

```
f[x_List]:=(x-Mean[x])/(Variance[x](Length@x-1))

g[x_List]:=#/Total[#^2]&@(x-Mean[x])

h[x_List]:= #/#.#&@(x-Mean[x])
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to avoid using temporary variables (avoiding duplication of code is the cause of having to use several steps) is to write an anonymous function.

```
(# - #2)/Sum[(i - #2)^2, {i, #}] &[x, Mean[x]]
```

But doing things in several steps isn't always wrong, it can make the code much more readable. One just has to remember to use `Module` so one doesn't pollute the name space and cause strange errors later on in the same session.

In the above code, `[x,Mean[x]]` has a duplicate x in it. If you only have `x` as an expression you don't want to substitute it in at two places, so you can do this:

```
(# - #2)/Sum[(i - #2)^2, {i, #}] &[#, Mean[#]] &[Range[10]]
```

Comment: This is great, gives me an idea of how to go on about solving other formulas that contain sum.

Comment: Why do you not want to substitute it in at two places?

Comment: @ALEXANDER Any duplication of code is not considered very good. Especially if it's computationally expensive. If `x` is, say, `Permutations[Range[10]]` (not cheap to compute) `[x,Mean[x]]` will compute it twice but `[#,Mean[#]]&[x]` will only compute it once.

Comment: And when I write x, I don't mean that you've previously executed `x=Permutations[Range[10]]`. I mean that you substitute `Permutations[Range[10]]` everywhere it says `x`.

Comment: Great thank you!